# JS Unity touchcreen script iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, touchscreen

I have a bit of a problem with coding my game in Unity, and I can't find any solution. I want to program a touchscreen, but on the certain rules which is included in picture below. 
[here is the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZDfc.png)

Red dots is the game objects which I should tap while gameplay is on, these red dots are moving to the center of black rectangle, and then they are lifted up.
I did program mechanic of movement of those dots. And problem starts here:
the black rectangle is the area where I can tap on those dots, and they will be destroyed, green X symbolizes that I can't touch red dots outside black area, because that wont affect them. After red dot reaches orange line, it can't be affected either. Only problem I have is to make mechanic of taping those dots on touchscreen in unity.

```
#pragma strict

var cow: GameObject;
var killzone: killzone;

function OnTriggerStay2D (killzone: Collider2D)
{
   if(Input.touchCount > 0)
 {
   if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
   {
     Destroy(cow);
   }
 }
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sorry about my incompleteness. Edit your post and add the code block.

Comment: I did post it as an anwser, check it out.